# how to make some changes in a perl script

Tags: arrays, perl, matrix, hash

Hi to all thanks to help me !!!

I have a list of taxonomic assignation (list of qiime), and I want to extract a list of bacterias using a list from a txt file; I have this code, that present 2 problems, one is that the taxonomic file have 2 lines that start with # (list of qiime), the first one (#Constructed from biom file) is the one that I want to avoid, the second one (#OTU ID .....samples) is the one that I use as a name of each column, I have tried something like

`if ($_=~ m/Constructed from biom file/){ next; }`

in different place of the code, but it just don't work (but when I eliminate that line from the file, it works well), but the point is that I don't want to manipulate the file, that is why I want to avoid that line.

The second problem (well is part of the code that I do't know how to make it), the script has a -s option, it mean that if I want an specific column, the script extract just the ones that I indicate (example: -s sample1,sample2,sample..n), the problem is that some times the selected samples have values of cero (0) in all the columns of any given row (xRow 0.0 0.0 0.0), in that case it must be avoid, in the script I use $val[1], but it is just for one sample, but if its 2 or mores samples it must avoid if present cero in all the row (in this case 3 samples).

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use List::Util qw(sum);

    my ($search_label, $infile_taxon, $infile_list, $output_file);

        GetOptions (
            'i=s'   =>\$infile_taxon,
            'l=s'   =>\$infile_list,
            's=s'   =>\$search_label,
            'o=s'   =>\$output_file,
            );

        sub match_genera {
            my ($List_File, $Taxon_File) = @_;
            my @lista_genera = @{ $List_File }; # dereferencing and copying each array
            my @taxon_qiime = @{ $Taxon_File };
            my (@extract);
                foreach (@lista_genera){
                    my $unit = $_;
                    chomp $unit;
                    my @match = grep (/$unit/, @taxon_qiime);
                             push (@extract, @match);
                }
                return @extract;
        }



    open INFILE_TAXONOMY, '<', "$infile_taxon" or die $!;
    open LIST_BACTERIA, '<', "$infile_list" or die $!;
    open OUTPUT, '>', "xfile2.txt" or die $!;

    chomp ( my @sample_names = split '\t', <INFILE_TAXONOMY> );
    shift @sample_names;
    unshift @sample_names, '#Genera';

    my (@ToExtract, @no_match, @filter, @filter_columns);

    # si ingresamos un -s
    if ($search_label){
        my @wanted= split (/\,/, $search_label); 
        unshift @wanted, '#Genera';
        @wanted = uniq (@wanted);

        foreach my $wanted_in (@wanted){
            if (my @match = grep (/$wanted_in/, @sample_names)) {
                push (@ToExtract, @match);
            }
            else {
                push (@no_match, $wanted_in);   
            }
        }

        if (grep {defined($_)} @no_match){
            print "\nSamples No Found: @no_match\n\n";
        }
        print OUTPUT join "\t", @ToExtract, "\n";
    }

    # si queremos toda la tabla !!
    else{
      @ToExtract = @sample_names;
      print OUTPUT join "\t", @ToExtract, "\n";
    }

    # Extraer los varoles de cada linea para cada variable !!!
    #my %row;
    while ( <INFILE_TAXONOMY> ){
        my %row;
        @row{@sample_names} = split "\t";
        @filter= join "\t", @row{@ToExtract};  
          push (@filter_columns, @filter); # ahora ya se puede usar con la 
    }

    my @list;
    foreach (<LIST_BACTERIA>){
        if ($_=~ m/^#|^$/)  {   next;           }
        else                {   push @list, $_  }
    }
    my @filter_list = uniq (@list);

    my @last = match_genera (\@filter_list, \@filter_columns);

    my (@genera_taxon, @genera_final);
    foreach (@last){
        @genera_taxon = ($_ =~ m/;D_5__(\w.*)/g);
                    foreach (@genera_taxon){
                        if ($_ =~ m/^$/g)   { next;                   }
                        else                { push @genera_final, $_; } 
                    }
    }

        foreach (@genera_final){ #split the line in a multiples var !!!
            chomp;
                   my @val = split (/\t/, $_);
                    foreach ($val[1]){
                        if ($_ == 0){ next; }
                        else{print join "\t", @val,"\n";}
                    }

                }

close INFILE_TAXONOMY;
close LIST_BACTERIA;
close OUTPUT;
exit;
```

taxonomic file (list of qiime) is a tab delimited text !!!:

```
#Constructed from biom file
#OTU ID sample1 sample2 sample3
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Holophagae;D_3__Subgroup 10;D_4__ABS-19;D_5__uncultured bacterium 0.002804    0.0073441109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Holophagae;D_3__Subgroup 10;D_4__CA002;D_5__uncultured bacterium  0.0 0.001109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Holophagae;D_3__Subgroup 10;D_4__Sva0725;D_5__uncultured bacterium    0.0 0.00882217  0.0014038202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Holophagae;D_3__Subgroup 7;D_4__uncultured bacterium;D_5__    0.0 0.0 0.00898876404
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 13;Ambiguous_taxa;D_4__;D_5__    0.0 0.0 0.00140449438202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 2;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__;D_5__  0.0 0.0 0.00280898876404
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 21;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__;D_5__ 0.0 0.0 0.00421348314607
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 22;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__;D_5__ 0.0 0.0 0.00421348314607
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 22;D_3__uncultured prokaryote;D_4__;D_5__    0.0 0.0 0.0014038202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 25;D_3__uncultured Acidobacteria bacterium;D_4__;D_5__   0.0012041933    0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 5;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__;D_5__  0.00120401933   0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 6;D_3__uncultured Acidobacteria bacterium;D_4__;D_5__    0.0 0.00115473441109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Acidobacteria;D_2__Subgroup 6;D_3__uncultured bacterium;D_4__;D_5__  0.00180614087899    0.0 0.00280898876404
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Acidimicrobiia;D_3__Acidimicrobiales;D_4__OM1 clade;D_5__uncultured actinobacterium  0.0 0.0 0.00140449438202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Acidimicrobiia;D_3__Acidimicrobiales;D_4__OM1 clade;D_5__uncultured bacterium    0.0 0.0 0.00561797752809
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Acidimicrobiia;D_3__Acidimicrobiales;D_4__Sva0996 marine group;D_5__uncultured bacterium 0.0 0.0 0.00280898876404
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Acidimicrobiia;D_3__Acidimicrobiales;D_4__uncultured;D_5__uncultured actinobacterium 0.00301023479831    0.00115473441109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Acidimicrobiia;D_3__Acidimicrobiales;D_4__uncultured;D_5__uncultured bacterium   0.000602059663  0.001173441109  0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Dietziaceae;D_5__Dietzia  0.0150511739916 0.0311778290993 0.00140449438202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Mycobacteriaceae;D_5__Mycobacterium   0.00240818865   0.002309882217  0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Nocardiaceae;D_5__Gordonia    0.0 0.0 0.00140449438202
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Nocardiaceae;D_5__Rhodococcus 0.00240865  0.0013441109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Nocardiaceae;D_5__Williamsia  0.0 0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__Tsukamurellaceae;D_5__Tsukamurella    0.000020463 0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Corynebacteriales;D_4__nbr16a11;D_5__uncultured bacterium    0.0014093   0.001134411 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Kineosporiales;D_4__Kineosporiaceae;D_5__Quadrisphaera   0.0 0.0014734   0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micrococcales;D_4__Demequinaceae;D_5__Lysinimicrobium    0.00120409391933    0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micrococcales;D_4__Intrasporangiaceae;D_5__Ornithinimicrobium    0.0006959663    0.0 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micrococcales;D_4__Intrasporangiaceae;D_5__Tetrasphaera  0.0 0.00441109  0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micrococcales;D_4__Micrococcaceae;D_5__Glutamicibacter   0.0 0.0031408776    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micrococcales;D_4__Micrococcaceae;D_5__Pseudarthrobacter 0.0 0.002882217 0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Micromonosporales;D_4__Micromonosporaceae;D_5__Actinoplanes  0.0 0.0011441109    0.0
D_0__Bacteria;D_1__Actinobacteria;D_2__Actinobacteria;D_3__Propionibacteriales;D_4__Propionibacteriaceae;D_5__Propionibacterium 0.3479831   0.0882217   0.00280898876404
```

list :

```
#list 
Gordonia
Mycobacterium
Ornithinimicrobium
Marinobacter
Pseudoalteromonas
Pseudomonas
Halomonas
Alcanivorax
Acinetobacter
Shewanella
Pseudidiomarina
Microbulbifer
Bacillus
Microbacterium
Achrornobacter
Actinomyces
Alcaligenes
```

print out expected (tab delimited):

```
#genera    sample1     sample3
Gordonia    0.00301023479831    0.00140449438202    
Mycobacterium   0.00240818783865    0.0 
Ornithinimicrobium  0.000602046959663   0.0 
Pseudomonas 0.367850692354  0.254213483146  
Halomonas   0.000602046959663   0.00140449438202    
Acinetobacter   0.00301023479831    0.00561797752809    
Bacillus    0.0626128838049 0.00280898876404    
Klebsiella  0.0138470800722 0.00280898876404    
Lactobacillus   0.000602046959663   0.0 
Acinetobacter   0.00301023479831    0.00561797752809    
Gordonia    0.00301023479831    0.00140449438202    
Rhodococcus 0.00240818783865    0.0 
Williamsia  0.000602046959663   0.0 
Streptomyces    0.000602046959663   0.0 
Dietzia 0.0150511739916 0.00140449438202    
Aquabacterium   0.000602046959663   0.0 
Janthinobacterium   0.0180614087899 0.0294943820225 
Massilia    0.000602046959663   0.00140449438202    
Noviherbaspirillum  0.000602046959663   0.0 
Rhodococcus 0.00240818783865    0.0 
Staphylococcus  0.166164960867  0.0688202247191 
Haemophilus 0.00120409391933    0.00280898876404    
Stenotrophomonas    0.000602046959663   0.00140449438202    
Candidatus Endomicrobium    0.00662251655629    0.0 
Candidatus Hepatincola  0.000602046959663   0.0
```

And the last one, I have try to make more simple the code, and in the new script I just trying to edit part of the code, trying to use an @newarray instead of < INFILE_TAXONOMY > to select the columns, in the new array the list is almost finished how I want (like the expected output) it just left to select the wanted columns,  how to make the next piece of the code with array.

```
while ( <INFILE_TAXONOMY> ){
        my %row;
        @row{@sample_names} = split "\t";
        @filter= join "\t", @row{@wanted};  
          push (@filter_columns, @filter);
    }
```

new script without the option to select an specific columns !!!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);


#---------------------------Subrutina de extraccion para 2 arrays de lista de bacterias y taxones!!-------------------------------------------------------------
         sub match_genera {
            my ($List_File, $Taxon_File) = @_;
            my @taxon_qiime = @{ $Taxon_File };
            my @lista_genera = @{ $List_File }; # dereferencing and copying each array
            my (@match, @extract, @genera_clean);

                  foreach (@taxon_qiime){
                     my @generas_taxon = ($_ =~ m/;D_5__(\w.*)/g);
                     foreach (@generas_taxon){
                        if ($_ =~ m/^$/g)   { next;                   }
                        else                { push @genera_clean, $_; } 
                     }
                  }

                  foreach (@lista_genera){
                    my $list_unit = $_;
                    chomp $list_unit;
                    @match = grep (/$list_unit/, @genera_clean);
                             push (@extract, @match);
                  }        
                return @extract;
         }
#------------------------------------------------------FILES-----------------------------------------------------------------------



            open INFILE_TAXONOMY, '<', "otu_table_L6_copy.txt" or die $!;
            open LIST_BACTERIA, '<', "lista_degradadoras.txt" or die $!;

            my (@lista_bacteria, @taxon, @sample_names);


# -------------------------------------------------------------TAXON -------------------------------------------------------------
                foreach (<INFILE_TAXONOMY>){
                     chomp;
                     if ($_=~ m/^$|Constructed from biom file/g)  {  next;                      }
                     elsif ($_ =~ s/OTU ID/Genera/g)              {  push @sample_names, $_;    }
                     else                                         {  push (@taxon, $_);         }
               }


# -------------------------------------------------------------LIST -------------------------------------------------------------
               foreach (<LIST_BACTERIA>){
                  if ($_=~ m/^$|^#/g)     {  next;                   }
                  else                    {  push @lista_bacteria, $_       }

               }
            my @filter_list = uniq (@lista_bacteria);

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            my @match_all = match_genera (\@filter_list, \@taxon);

            unshift @match_all, @sample_names;

            @wanted= qw(sample1 sample3);

            foreach (@match_all){
               print "$_\n";
               }

            close INFILE_TAXONOMY;
            close LIST_BACTERIA;
            exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
chomp ( my @sample_names = split '\t', <INFILE_TAXONOMY> );
```

with

```
<INFILE_TAXONOMY>;  # Skip first line.
chomp ( my @sample_names = split '\t', <INFILE_TAXONOMY> );
```

or

```
my $sample_names;
while ($sample_names = <INFILE_TAXONOMY>) {
   chomp($sample_names);
   last if $sample_names !~ /Constructed from biom file/;
}

defined($sample_names)
   or die("Premature EOF");

my @sample_names = split /\t/, $sample_names;
```

Comment: thanks so much, the second option works well, thanks !!